# SVN - how to create trunk directory without adding a revision?

Tags: svn

How can I create a trunk directory in an empty svn repository, without creating a revision?

I can easily add the trunk dir with svn mkdir file:///path/to/repo/trunk, but this adds r1 to the repository, so when importing an svn dump, all revisions are revision+1 from the original repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The revision number in your svn repository is a running count of the changes that have been in the repository, and creating a directory is a change.

Don't put so much significance on the revision number. It's nothing more than a counter.